# install Kuman 3.5 pouce LCD TFT Screen raspberry pi 3 raspian 7

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen

i use a raspberry pi for the first time and I don't have any programmation skills.
 I acquired a Kuman 3.5 pouce LCD TFT Screen (https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B01CNLYL1C/ref=pe_386181_51767671_TE_dp_1) for my raspberry pi 3.

From my labtop I installed raspian jessie (zip download and image write on the SD card with the  win32disk imager software).

I put my sd card into the raspberry and the OS works but I don't know how to install the screen, I search on forum but nothing works I have a white screen.

Also when tutorial said to download an image to install the screen: should I install win32disk on the raspberry to be able to write the screen image?  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

To start using the screen you would need to install the driver that is supplied on the DVD. Or you could download it from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git
```

Once cloning is finished got into the LCD-show directory and run `tft35-show` to install the drivers. The script will automatically reboot the pi.

I Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, to run the screen at every boot, a change in crontab or rc.local is needed.